# UTF-8 Hex code to Unicode

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, hex

Lets say I have string in Russian cyrillics "**журнал**", which has following hex code:

```
d0 b6 d1 83 d1 80 d0 bd d0 b0 d0 bb
```

But how can I convert this hex code back to human readable cyrillics string **in PHP**? I have checked so many sources, nothing have worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
function hex2str($hex) {
    $str = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($hex); $i += 2) {
        $str .= chr(hexdec(substr($hex, $i, 2)));
    }
    return $str;
}

$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', 'd0 b6 d1 83 d1 80 d0 bd d0 b0 d0 bb');

echo hex2str($string);
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I saw similar function before, I didn't know that I need to remove whitespaces.